# I am concatenating two different CNN model trained on two completely different dataset

Tags: cnn

**My model is going in the infinite loop while predicting( full_model.predict(inputgenerator)). I think there is some issue with the datagenerator code that I have written(especially with while loop).please help me)**

Dataset_A/

```
           Train/

                          Type_1/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

                          Type_2/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

           Test/

                          Type_1/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

                          Type_2/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..
```

Dataset_B/

```
           Train/

                          Type_1/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

                          Type_2/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

           Test/

                          Type_1/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..

                          Type_2/

                                         Image_0

                                         Image_1

                                         …..
```

CODE

```
input_imgen_1 = ImageDataGenerator()
input_imgen_2 = ImageDataGenerator()

def generate_generator_multiple(generator_1, generator_2 ,dir1, dir2, batch_size, img_height,img_width):
    gen1 = generator_1.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'binary',
                                          batch_size = 16,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
        
    gen2 = generator_2.flow_from_directory(dir2,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'binary',
                                          batch_size = 16,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    while True:
      X1i = gen1.next()
      X2i = gen2.next()
      yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]  #X1i[1] is the label
          
inputgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(generator_1 = input_imgen_1, generator_2 = input_imgen_2,
                                           dir1='dataset_A_path',
                                           dir2=' dataset_B_path  ',
                                           batch_size=16,
                                           img_height=390,
                                           img_width=390) 

###CNN_for_dataset_1

input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(390, 390, 3))
conv2d_p1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(input_1)
conv2d_p2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_p1)
conv2d_p3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_p2)
maxpool_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2d_p3)
conv2d_p4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_p3)
conv2d_p5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_p4)
maxpool_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2d_p5)

###CNN_for_dataset_2

input_2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(390, 390, 3))
conv2d_b1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(input_2)
conv2d_b2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_b1)
conv2d_b3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_b2)
maxpool_3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2d_b3)
conv2d_b4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_b3)
conv2d_b5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(conv2d_b4)
maxpool_4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2d_b5)

####concatenate_both_CNN
concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([maxpool_2, maxpool_4])

flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(concat)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu)(flatten)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(dense)
full_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[output])

full_model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
###training 
full_model.fit(inputgenerator, steps_per_epoch = 8, epochs = 2, use_multiprocessing=True)

###predication

predictions = full_model.predict(inputgenerator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while True:` loop in `generate_generator_multiple` never terminates, so even though the generators are exhausted, the loop will attempt to execute further calls to `next`. I would expect those to raise `StopIteration` exceptions, though -- I'm not sure why you're not seeing those.

As long as you know that `gen1` and `gen2` are the same length, I might expect code more like:

```py
for X1i in gen1:
      X2i = gen2.next()
      yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]
```

Comment: "5564/Unknown - 597s 107ms/step" its again going in infinite loop during prediction